# ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week ("N") in PHP using the date() function always returns 3

Tags: php, date, dayofweek, mktime

Trying to get the ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week ("N") in PHP using the date() function; however, it keeps returning "3" no matter what day I use with mktime().

```
<?php

$date = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 16, 2011) );
//$date = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 17, 2011) );

print_r(date('N', $date));

?>
```

Output: 3

Comment: When simple stuff doesn't work, read the documentation. The date() function takes a timestamp; you're passing it a string. See salathe's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is trying to interpret the string generated by `date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 16, 2011) );` as a date, but PHP uses seconds since epoch as a datatime. You can just pass the result of mktime into the second data function call like this:

```
$dateTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 16, 2011)
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",  $dateTime);
echo date('N', $dateTime);
// results in "5"
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't feed a date string into the second argument for `date()`, it should be an integer containing the Unix timestamp (the value returned from `mktime()`). See the [`date()` documentation](http://php.net/date).

```
$date = mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 16, 2011);
var_dump(date('N', $date)); // string(1) "5"
```

---

With your original code:

```
$date = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, 9, 16, 2011) );
print_r(date('N', $date));
```

The value of `$date` is `"2011-09-16 00:00:00"`.  This is not an integer, and certainly not the Unix timestamp for that date/time; because of that, `date()` cannot work with the value and reverts back to using the Unix epoch (`0` timestamp) which is 1 Jan 1970.  Also, an `E_NOTICE` message stating "*A non well formed numeric value encountered in [file] on line [line]*" is issued.